# this code gives an index error. the code of my instructor had another string passed in the test_board which was not shown in the output also

Tags: python

```
from IPython.display import clear_output

def display_board(board):
     clear_output()
     print(board[7]+'|'+board[8]+'|'+board[9])
     print('-|-|-')
     print(board[4]+'|'+board[5]+'|'+board[6])
     print('-|-|-')
     print(board[1]+'|'+board[2]+'|'+board[3])
test_board = ['o','d','s','d','a','a','d','e','w']
display_board(test_board)
```

Hi there my instructor's code had an extra string in the test_board variable I just didn't understand why as there are only 9 parameters included why should we print 10 strings. Thank you,

Comment: Instead of starting with 1, start with 0.

Answer (score 1):

In python(and as far as I know, in every other programming languages), List(and Array) indexing starts from 0 not 1.
For example:

```
A = ['a', 'b', 'c']
print(A[0])
#Output: a
print(A[2])
#Output: c
print(A[3])
#Output: Index error
```

`A[3]` raises an index error because A has three elements that their indexes are 0, 1, and 2. So, there is no element with index 3 in A